# iText - Remove Document Level Javascripts

Tags: itext, itext7

Using the iText PDF libraries (v7), does anyone have any advice on how to  remove 'Document-level' JavaScripts from PDFs?  I have figured out how to remove Page-Level JavaScripts, but cannot seem to figure out how to remove those at the document-level.  Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

I got this resolved and below is the snippet of code (C#) in case anyone else needs it:

```
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SOURCE), new PdfWriter(TARGET));
        PdfCatalog pdfCat = pdfDoc.GetCatalog();
        PdfDictionary names = pdfCat.GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);

        names.Remove(PdfName.JavaScript);

        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Did not work for me. names is always null, regardless if the document has JavaScript or not. Though it may be due to specifics of a particular document, I failed to remove them manually (via Adobe Standard) either.